# Is Map a function with Two Arguments?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve a multiple choice question that states the following

- map is an overloaded function
- map is a polymorphic function
- map is a curried function
- map is a higher-order function
- map is a function with two arguments

I know that map is overloaded, polymorphic, curried and higher-order. Does that mean that map is a function with just a single argument ? (I realize that this is a consequence of a function being curried, and haskell only has functions with single arguments with multiple argument functions being applied through currying and partial application)

Is the reasoning correct ? And if so, how does the map function evaluate a function through partial application ?

Comment: `map` is not a overloaded function. Overloaded implies that compiler will choose different implementation of that function according to the types of its arguments. That is not how `map` works. Beside that, a function cannot (can it?) be both overloaded and polymorphic.

Comment: @Lee: I'm not sure if Haskell can be said to have overloaded functions at all; I suppose that's one way to look at type class methods, but not a very good one. But anyway, even in a language that has overloaded functions, being both overloaded and polymorphic doesn't really make much sense per se; what can happen though, is that a function can be overloaded and one or several of its implementations are polymorphic. For example, you can have a function with two implementations, a monomorphic one of type `Int -> String` and a polymorphic one of type `[a] -> String`.

Comment: @Lee - I thought map wasn't an overloaded function, however the [map documentation page](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=map) lists different implementations of the map function.

Doesn't that make it overloaded, by your definition ?

Comment: @WasifHyder these are just different functions with the same name. If two different modules exports a `map` function, Haskell will require you to explicitly specify which one you're using. So the answer is no.

Comment: @WasifHyder To be an overloaded function, 1) there must be more than one implementations for that function, 2) compiler will choose specific implementation *automatically* according to the types of its arguments of a specific call of that function. There are two requirements for a function to be overloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all Haskell functions, `map` is a single-argument function. Let's have a look at its type signature:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

I think this signature is easier to understand in your case: `map` gets one argument - a function from `a` to `b` - and returns another function, this time from `[a]` to `[b]`.

Essentialy, `map` "lifts" a function - it takes a regular function and "lifts" it so it'll work on lists. This idea of [lifting](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lifting) appears in several places in Haskell.

For example, `even` is a function from `Int` to `Bool` - it takes a number and returns true iff it is even. And `map even` is a function from `[Int]` to `[Bool]` - it takes a list of numbers and returns a list of boolean values. `map even` is just `even` working in a different "context" - lists instead of single values.

Answer (score 1):

You can say `map` takes two argument, but in reality every function in Haskell takes only one argument. Inspect it's type:

```
λ> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So `map` seems to take two argument according to it's type definition. But since curring takes place in Haskell, you can say that it takes an argument of type `(a -> b)` and returns `[a] -> [b]`. And because of currying you can do stuffs like this in which it takes one argument as a parameter and doesn't throw compile error:

```
λ> let a = map (+ 3)
```

The *point* is knowing the difference between how curring makes any function to take one argument and return one argument and understanding the general type definition of any function to see what it takes. Every function in Haskell actually takes only one parameter because of currying.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was taken from https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x-0:

Exercise:

Which of the following statements about the Prelude function map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] is false:

"map is a function with two arguments"

"map is an overloaded function"

...

Actually they agree that "map is an overloaded function" is False, and so "map is a function with two arguments" becomes True.