# How does the map() function in JS work with two arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845105/is-map-a-function-with-two-arguments), however, according to the [official React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), you can do this.

```
const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

and the history object looks like

```
history = [
  // Before first move
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  },
  // After first move
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, 'X', null,
      null, null, null,
    ]
  },
  // After second move
  {
    squares: [
      null, null, null,
      null, 'X', null,
      null, null, 'O',
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

My understanding is that the map function acts like a "foreach" loop. For each item in the original object. How can you say, in effect, "for each this and that?"

Comment: You can't, and using `.map` like `.forEach` is bad practice. The *callback* (i.e. the single argument) you pass to map() uses two arguments: the array element and optionally, its index. It's supposed to return a transformed array element. In React, this is typically used for list rendering, where an array of data elements is transformed into an array `<li>`s or other DOM elements.

Comment: So does the second argument of map() automatically get the index?

Comment: There is no second argument to map(). However when the callback (which is the single argument) is called, then yes, the element is passed as first argument, and its array index as 2nd argument.

Comment: @MeowMeow No, there is no second argument to `.map()`. I think what you are referring to is the second argument of the callback function *passed into* `.map()`. In that case, yes, it will return the index of the item for which the callback was called.

Comment: Can you explain what "step" does and what "move" does here?

Comment: `step` is the first argument of the callback function, and contains `{ squares: [...] }`, while `move` is the index and will be `0`, then `1`, then `2`.

Comment: @MeowMeow Not sure if this helps, but this is essentially a very verbose version of exactly what `Array.map()` does internally - it iterates over the array, collects the return value of the callback for each item, and returns a new array. https://jsfiddle.net/tnuchkpd/1/

Comment: Do you people(Chris & mhodges, anyone else) even read official [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `array.prototype.map` accepts 2 parameters, a `callback` function, and a `thisArg` value; the `callback` accepts up to 3 parameters. @MeowMeow your question is unclear. What are you really wanting to know/understand? Array.map does iterate over an array and return a value for every element that was iterated. The result is a new array of the same length with a one-to-one relationship to all elements of the original array.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, very helpful Drew! Thanks for letting the OP know they can provide their own `this` context to .map(), I think that will definitely help them solve their issue... *for the OP's intents and purposes* the 2nd parameter to `.map()` is irrelevant. We are focusing on the parameters of the callback. Likewise, the 3rd parameter to the callback in this case is also irrelevant. But I did provide it in the example of a custom map function if that makes you feel better.

Comment: @DrewReese

In those docs I see    let newArray = arr.map(callback(currentValue[, index[, array]])

I would understand let newArray = arr.map(callback(currentValue, index, array) but I have never seen a square bracket within the callback args.

Comment: That is just a common syntax for additional optional parameters. Sometimes you may seem them written as `arr.map(callback(currentValue, ?index, ?array), ?thisArg)` or similar.

Comment: @DrewReese I mean.. if you want to get really technical, the `currentValue` parameter is entirely optional, too.

Comment: @DrewReese oh wait I think I get it. It is saying the args can be.
[1,2.3] OR [1,2] OR [1]]